# how do I make it work the .env in the firebase keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, environment-variables

I forgot how to setup the firebase process environment in a .dotenv files. I already installed the `npm i dotenv` but it seems like it doesn't work. I'm using CRA.

This is the .env file

```
REACT_API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxx"
REACT_AUTH_DOMAIN="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
REACT_PROJECT_ID="xxxxxxxxxx"
REACT_STORAGE_BUCKET="xxxxxxxxxxx"
REACT_MESSAGE_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
REACT_APP_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

this is the firebase.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getAuth,GoogleAuthProvider, FacebookAuthProvider, TwitterAuthProvider,GithubAuthProvider  } from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_MESSAGE_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app)
export const storage = getStorage(app)
export const authentication = getAuth();
export const google = new GoogleAuthProvider()
export const facebook = new FacebookAuthProvider()
export const twitter = new TwitterAuthProvider()
export const github = new GithubAuthProvider()
```

However I'm receiving this kind of error.

```
ERROR
Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
    at createErrorInternal (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2563:38)
    at _assert (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2570:11)
    at Component.instanceFactory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12176:5)
    at Provider.getOrInitializeService (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89335:33)
    at Provider.initialize (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89276:27)
    at initializeAuth (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5056:25)
    at getAuth (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12268:16)
    at ./src/lib/firebase.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1939:78)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:93520:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:92966:33)
```

Can anyone tell me how to setup again the process env in the firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Create-React-App as your build tool, the correct wording should be REACT_APP_

For example
REACT_API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxx" should be
REACT_APP_API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxx"